# How to make Google News on Android and iOS show large images as website developer?

Tags: html, microdata, xml-sitemap, google-news

Even though we have a dedicated XML with articles for Google News and we also provide the images in the XML via

```
<i:image>
  <i:loc>https://...</i:loc>
  <i:caption>Image description</i:caption>
</i:image>
```

the Google News reader on Android and iOS displays our articles using a 100x100 image stretched to fit the device screen which of course looks awful. What can I do as website developer to tell Google News to use larger resolution images?

Answer (score 0):

It's about the images that you submit via structured data (Schema.org). There you need to specify the path to the image(s), ideally you have them in three different sizes (small, medium, big).

I recommend to read this article to learn everything about the images, sizes and structured data you need to perfectly cater to Google's guidelines.

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/mobile/google-discover